# swapping a 1uf 200v axial capacitor for a .9uf 200v axial capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I have a bad axial type .9uf 200v capacitor in the power supply of an old turntable. Can I substitute a 1uf 200v axial capacitor in its place?

Comment: Likely. Specifics of why it wouldn't be would require a lot more context.

Answer (score 3):

Capacitors typically have rather a broad tolerance. There is little practical difference between a 0.9uF capacitor and a 1.0uF capacitor.

However, there may be some cases where the exact value of a capacitor is important. For example if this capacitor is part of the motor, you may not get full performance (time to start, torque, etc.) if the capacitor is too far from the design value.

It would be easier to answer this if we knew exactly WHERE this capacitor is in the circuit.

Comment: The capacitor is on the motor board of the turntable.  The problem that is occurring is that the speed of the platter is fluctuating.  I can post a link to the service manual which contains a schematic, but you are going to have to register on Vinylengine.com

Comment: http://www.vinylengine.com/library/jvc/srp-471e.shtml